# MySQL/SQL Command Problem should be Simple

Tags: mysql, sql

I don't know what I do false, Here the Code:

```
`UPDATE `Players` SET `online` = 0 WHERE `uuid` = `5f1d55a9-0e01-4540-a978-6697fdf2db1f`;`
```

Here the error:

> SQL-Command:
>   UPDATE `Players` SET `online` = 0 WHERE `uuid` = `5f1d55a9-0e01-4540-a978-6697fdf2db1f`
>   MySQL alerts: Dokumentation
>
> ## 1054 - Unknown table field '5f1d55a9-0e01-4540-a978-6697fdf2db1f' in where clause

[image]

[image]

Comment: you don't use ticks  for wrapping string but single/double quotes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using single quotes for strings and don't bother escaping other identifiers:

```
UPDATE Players
    SET online = 0
    WHERE uuid = '5f1d55a9-0e01-4540-a978-6697fdf2db1f';
```

Easier to read as well as write.

Answer (score 0):

just use single quotes NOT ticks. Below query should work

```
update players
set online = 0
where uuid = '5f1d55a9-0e01-4540-a978-6697fdf2db1f';
```